# Is it safe to cast bool to float?

Tags: c++

I wonder if directly casting `bool` to `float` is safe to use.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool b1 = false;
    bool b2 = true;
    float f1 = static_cast<float>(b1);
    float f2 = static_cast<float>(b2);
    cout << "False in float : " << f1 << endl;
    cout << "True in float : " << f2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
False in float : 0                                                                                          
True in float : 1
```

Would the result be identical in all C++ compilers and platforms?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it should be safe across all compilers and platforms, this rule is guaranteed by the standard.

[C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf), Section 4.9, Floating-integral conversions tells us:

> If the source type is bool, the value *false* is converted to zero and the value *true* is converted to one.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this has been allowed and defined since the first C++ standard, ISO/IEC 14882:1998.

*4.9 Floating-integral conversions [conv.fpint]* says:

> 2. An rvalue of an integer type or of an enumeration type can be converted to an rvalue of a floating point type. The result is exact if possible. Otherwise, it is an implementation-defined choice of either the next lower or higher representable value. [*Note:* loss of precision occurs if the integral value cannot be represented exactly as a value of the floating type. ] **If the source type is `bool`, the value `false` is converted to zero and the value `true` is converted to one.**

(Emphasis mine.)